# Prestashop home page not loading properly

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I just installed Prestashop 1.6.1.1 at openshift hosting. Admin panel works fine but home page is not loading properly.

http://brinquedos3-pettool.rhcloud.com/

Comment: Did your prestashop shop install successfully? Was there any error while installing.

Comment: yes, it is installed successfully.

Comment: Was your issue solved?  If yes, would be great if you could answer your own question so this doesn't show up as un-answered and others can learn from it too. (or you can delete the question if it's to much work for you) Thanks for your understanding and cooperation.

Comment: @Harendra, Since the link is now invalid, please delete the question